# How to pass a string var into Hash#rassoc?

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-1.9.3

I'm trying to get key by value, but want to set a request dynamic throw the string variable.

```rb
presidents = { 1 => "Washington", 2 => "Adams", 3 => "Jefferson" }

request1 = gets
request2 = "Adams"

puts presidents.rassoc(request1).first # doesn't work
puts presidents.rassoc(request2).first # work perfect
```

The second method gives an error, when i type "Adams" and press Enter:

```
test.rb:6:in `<main>': undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I also checked `request1` and `request2` classes - both `String`

I read the description of the [rassoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-rassoc), but still do not understand why the second does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a chomp on `gets`:

```
# If the user types 'Washington'
gets       #=> "Washington\n"
gets.chomp #=> "Washington"
```

Comment: @ramilmuratov Always check your data to see if the assumptions you're making are correct :)

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, but some data are implicit, especially for a beginner :)

Comment: @RamilMuratov Data is never "implicit"; if something using non-code artifacts doesn't work, one of the primary rules of debugging is to check your inputs. This is particularly true when storing/retrieving based on data.